# Convert array of objects post splitting them in half: Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I have an array of array of objects similar to this:

```
arr = [{ val: 1, ts : 123},{val: 2, ts : 125},{val: 3,ts : 120}, {val: 4, ts : 113} , {val:5, ts : 117},{ val: 6, ts : 143},{val: 7, ts : 193},{val: 8, ts : 187}, {val: 9, ts : 115} , {val:10,ts : 116}]
```

The length of the array is always an even number. Now basically I'd like to split them in 2 halves.

```
split1 = [{ val: 1, ts : 123},{val: 2, ts : 125},........,{val:5, ts : 117}]
split2 = [{ val: 6, ts : 143},{val: 7, ts : 193},........,{val:10,ts : 116}]
```

I have to map over these arrays and transform their fields(first item of array1 with first item of array2 and so on). Say the first array is called "old" array with objects having(keys val and ts) and second array is called "new" array with objects having(keys val and ts) . So I have map them and the final should look like this

```
final = [
          { oldVal:1, oldts: 123 , newVal:6, newts: 143},
          { oldVal:2, oldts: 125 , newVal:7, newts: 193},
          { oldVal:3, oldts: 120 , newVal:8, newts: 187},
          { oldVal:4, oldts: 113 , newVal:9, newts: 115},
          { oldVal:5, oldts: 117 , newVal:10, newts: 116},
        ]
```

What I have tried is:

```
var res= a.splice(0, arr.length/2);
var c = a.map((val, ind) => { {val, res[ind]} })
```

Can someone guide here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply iterate over half of the array, and take the `i`th element and `i + half`th as its pair:

```js
const arr = [{ val: 1, ts : 123},{val: 2, ts : 125},{val: 3,ts : 120}, {val: 4, ts : 113} , {val:5, ts : 117},{ val: 6, ts : 143},{val: 7, ts : 193},{val: 8, ts : 187}, {val: 9, ts : 115} , {val:10,ts : 116}];

const final = [];
const half = arr.length / 2;
for (let i = 0; i < half; i++) {

  final.push({
    oldVal: arr[i].val,
    oldTs: arr[i].ts,
    newVal: arr[i + half].val,
    newTs: arr[i + half].ts,
  });
}

console.log(final);
```

Comment: sorry there isnt a val1 in source array, its val all across. modified the question

Comment: You can also do this via `.map` if you do `arr.slice(0, half).map((item, index) => [item, arr[index+half]])`

Comment: @VLAZ but then I would have to run `.map` again to make it an array of objects, would I? Or am I missing your point?

Comment: It was just shorthand example to show going through both halves of the array at once. Yes, you still need to produce the desired objects, just mentioning an option with `.map`.

Comment: Just leaving this here.  Just looping through like Sebastian has here is definitely cleaner.  `(arr.splice(0,arr.length/2))
        .map( ( {val:oldVal,ts:oldts} , ind ) =>
          ({
           oldVal,
           oldts,
           newVal:arr[ind].val,
           newts:arr[ind].ts
          })
        )`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you have to slice the array or not, but that's my approach :

```js
arr = [{ val: 1, ts : 123},{val: 2, ts : 125},{val: 3,ts : 120}, {val: 4, ts : 113} , {val:5, ts : 117},{ val1: 6, ts : 143},{val1: 7, ts : 193},{val1: 8, ts : 187}, {val1: 9, ts : 115} , {val1:10,ts : 116}];
let final = [];
arr.forEach(function(v, i) {
    if (i >= arr.length / 2) return false;
    final[i] = {oldVal: v.val, oldTs: v.ts, newVal: arr[i + arr.length / 2].val, newTs: arr[i + arr.length / 2].ts}
});
console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a single loop approach and change the value as the array loops.

```js
var data = [{ val: 1, ts: 123 }, { val: 2, ts: 125 }, { val: 3, ts: 120 }, { val: 4, ts: 113 }, { val: 5, ts: 117 }, { val: 6, ts: 143 }, { val: 7, ts: 193 }, { val: 8, ts: 187 }, { val: 9, ts: 115 }, { val: 10, ts: 116 }],
    result = data.reduce((r, { val, ts }, i, { length }) => {
        const index = i % (length >> 1);
        if (r[index]) {
            r[index].newVal = val;
            r[index].newts = ts;
        } else {
            r[index] = { oldVal: val, oldts: ts };
        }
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: what does i % (length >> 1) do?

Answer (score 0):

```
var newArr = [];
var half = Math.floor(arr.length / 2);

for (var i = 0; i < half; i++){
    newArr.push({oldVal: arr[i].val, oldTs: arr[i].ts, newVal: arr[i + half].val, newTs: arr[i + half].ts}) 
}
```

**P.S If your original array has even length you will have leftover item